# Type parameter constraint that disregards generic type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, asp.net-identity

I have EntityBase abstract class which normally all of my entities inherit from. It takes a generic type that specifies the type of the Id property (e.g. int or Guid). EntityBase also contains some logic to determine equality between entities.

```
public abstract class EntityBase<T>
{
    public T Id { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

In my .Net Core 2.2 web application, I'm using Asp.Net Identity and I have an entity named ApplicationUser that must inherit from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser. Because it's not possible to inherit from multiple base classes, I can't inherit from EntityBase.

So, I created an interface named IEntity which both EntityBase and ApplicationUser implement

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Id { get; }
}
```

I have a IRepository interface that with a generic type that must be an entity. I don't care what the type of the Id is on that entity. I just want to be able to say that TEntity just needs to be some IEntity and I don't care if it's IEntity or IEntity. Something like the below. Is this possible?

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
}
```

Comment: IEntity is just something that doesn't exist, you defined IEntity<T> and this means, you always have to provide a Type Parameter.
If you want to enforce your TEntity must implement IEntity<T> you just have to append <T>, but to define what T is, you have to have interface IRepository<TEntity, T>

Answer (score 1):

The only way to constraint to `IEntity<T>` is by saying:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : IEntity<TId>
{
}
```

You need to specify the type parameter. If you think about it, a constraint that disregards the `T` in `IEntity<T>` would be useless: you wouldn't be able to use the `Id` property, because you wouldn't know its type, and that's the only thing that is contracted by `IEntity<T>`.

If you say that you don't care about the type of `Id` then well, why do you care that that thing is an `IEntity<T>` at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface without a parameter that all entities derive from

```
public interface IEntity
{
}
public interface IEntity<out T> : IEntity
{
    T Id { get; }
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T> : IEntity<T>
{
    public T Id { get; private set; }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity: IEntity
{
}
```

Comment: What is the use of such an empty interface, though? What's the contract enforced?

Comment: It just a base class, with no contracts. All classes that implement `Entity<T>` inherit from it and so they are _assumed_ to have an `Id` property. You cannot got from `IEntity` to reading the property, it has to be done via the concrete implementation of each entity.

Comment: An interface is not a "base class". An empty interface like `IEntity` doesn't serve any purpose as far as I can see. You're just artificially making your type hierarchy more complicated.

Comment: @V0ldek - `IEntity` is just the common ancestor of all entities. In order to work with a hierarchy you often need to know a common ancestor if it is not `object`. That is a requirement of OOP design, and C# doesn't have a way to reference all `IEntity<>` types without a generic specifier.

Comment: But _why_ do you need a common ancestor of all entities? An `object` provides methods that every .NET object has to have. What does an empty `IEntity` interface provide? What is the value in constraining your generic types to that empty interface? It's completely artificial.

Comment: @V0ldek - the value is that you _know_ it is not an `integer` or a `string`, but something that _should_ implement a property `Id` down the line. You could cast `IEntity` into a concrete class if you design it in a way you know what you have, or use pattern matching.